# Ember js how can i run a function after model change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am using materialize css library and it says

> Collapsible elements only need initialization if they are added dynamically

And i add some elements dynamically. So after the view is rendered i should run this function:

```
$('.collapsible').collapsible({
  accordion : false 
});
```

In `setupController` function i make some requests and after every request finished i setup the controller. When controller gets the model and after the view is rendered with the new model data i should run a function to initialize the ui elments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to setup an ember.js component for your accordion and use the didInsertElement hook:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['.collapsible'],
  didInsertElement() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      this.$().collapsible({
        accordion: false
      });
    });
  },     
});
```